# Receiving NULL on response error body if the status code is 400 with retrofit in android

Tags: android, node.js, nullpointerexception, retrofit, retrofit2

I was working on some login process and got stuck. The problem was when i enter a wrong password it always throws the NullPointerException because my getMessage was receiving null response from backend. After that what i did was i changed my status code in node from 400 to 200 (200 - which i am using for success status) and then tried same procedure, After entering wrong password this time it gave me the response from the node.

Which means my retrofit is not receiving response for status code 400 and when changed it to 200 it worked well that was really weird.

Anyone know why this is happening if you want me to post my login or node code i can.

THANKS !

**EDIT**

This is my onResponse method in login activity.

```
 public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();

            if (resp.getmessage().equals(Constants.SUCCESS))
            {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, resp.getmessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                goToProfile();

        }
        else {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, resp.getmessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

**and here is my node code, currently all status codes are 200 but when i used 400 for wrong password and user not fount it returns null.**

```
const User= require("../model/user.model.js");
const { initSession} = require('../utils/utils');

const logins =  (req,res,next)=> {  
console.log("login user::"+JSON.stringify(req.body));
console.log("password:::"+req.body.user.password);  
 User.findOne({ username : req.body.user.username }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {           
          return res.status(200).send({
              message : "User not found."
          });
      }    
      else {    

        if (user.validPassword(req.body.user.password)) {   
            console.log("login successfully!!!");            
            return res.status(200).send({
                message : "success"
            });

        }        
    else if(!(user.validPassword(req.body.user.password))) {
        console.log("wrong password");
        return res.status(200).send({
            message : "Wrong Password"
        });
    }
}
  })
  }

module.exports = { logins };
```

Comment: Please add related code to the post.

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk I have edited the post with my onResponse method and node code  you can check

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk  ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you receive error retrofit isn't parsing it but passing it as an errorBody.

So you need to parse this json: `response.errorBody().string()` to your `ServerResponse` object and then you can access `message` property.

**Edit:**

Your response function:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body()
        if(serverResponse.getMessage().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.body().getMessage()).show();
            goToProfile();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ServerResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ServerResponse.class);
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, errorResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: where? i need to do that in my else condition or just i need to parse the json in onResponse first , can you exactly what you mean i didn't get you

Comment: @Prashantsingh if the answer helped you, you could help me by marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: hey i am sorry for the late response, but after editing my code with your suggestions , when i tried to run the app the buld failed and shows an error

Comment: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: hey it was nothing but just a bug in android studio, i cleaned and rebuild the project and boom it worked.

Comment: **THANKS !**   **happy coding !**